# Fastest way to solve any python program containing bitwise operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time, bit-manipulation

I have a program in which I need to find the maximum value of expression.
The expression is :

```
result=(x&z)*(y&z)
```

in which the value of z is in the range of [l,r].
I have written a program about it which is absolutely correct.

```
# cook your dish here
t=int(input())

for i in range(t):
    x,y,l,r=map(int,input().split())
    L=[]
    I=[]
    for i in range(l,r+1):
        r=(x&i)*(y&i)
        L.append(r)
        I.append(i)
    R=max(L)
    i=L.index(R)
    print(L)
    print(I[i])
```

I want to a faster way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` will be maximized when the product is of the numbers `x*y` itself as `A&B` can't exceed `min(A,B)`, Whatever the range `l,r+1` might be. in this case `x|y` will give a number with which doing `AND` with either `x` or `y` will return the same number

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: It's just that the value of Z that you're looking for will be at least `x|y` try it out on a piece of paper with bit representation of numbers that you'll take as x and y. Example x=600 y=900, now If you try brute forcing between a range say (0,2000). You'll get the value as 988. which is basically `x|y` which will get 600&988=600 and 900&988=900

Comment: but it needs to be in this range

Comment: That you should do it on your own